# Execute irc action on computer

Tags: linux, irc

Just as the title says, I want a command be done when a certain word is said in my irc channel.

Ex: If someone types "Hey!" in the channel, the server performs an action like restarting an services.

The channel is private and only I will be getting access to it.
The purpose of it will be that if I send a command from my office that I want to restart Apache (example).
Then I'll type apacherst, the irc sends the command to my server and restarts apache.

Any idea?

Thanks!
/Phew

Comment: This looks like a job for a [irc bot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_bots).

Comment: Thanks for the tips @ibizaman
Need to look a little bit deeper to this, dont really know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out a program called [Hubot](http://hubot.github.com/). It has a plug-in mechanism to let make your chat server extensible. It supports IRC and many other protocols.

Comment: Seconding Hubot.  With a couple lines of coffeescript you could have it shell out to "ssh user@host sudo apachectl restart", not sure you want to give your IRC bot SSH keys + passwordless sudo access to your machines, but it's totally doable.